# Delete a node without head pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I read that it is possible to delete a node from a linked list,of which head pointer is not given, only if it is not the last linked list.
The cpp code is as follows,

```
Node *r=node->next;
node->data=r->data;
node->next=r->next;
free(r);
```

I read that this code cannot be used to delete last linked list,we need to put extra conditions.I cant understand why?

Comment: What happens if `node` is the last item?  Think about what value `r` will have, and what will happen when you access `r->data` and `r->next`.

Comment: what is "cpp" code?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

+Did you return the pointer of your linked list ?
+You set the `C` tag but you talck about cpp.

Considere giving us the code around this 4 lines.

The reason why this code can't be use as it is for deleting the last node is because you first need to get the adresse of this last node by crawling thought your next pointers until you find NULL. (with something like this: )

```
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
        ptr = ptr->next;
```

after this ptr will be equals to your last node adresse. With this adresse you can do what ever you want.

Exemple: if you save the head node you can place the last as first **or** you can even delete the last node ..etc

With the code you send you only copy the data of the second list into the first one